# Remove to large gradients from columns in dataframe/tipple

Tags: r

I'm generating a dataframe (or better, a tipple) using measurement data from a database and put it using pivot_wider into the wide form:

```
library(DBI)
library(tidyr)

con <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(), 
                 dbname='mainscnt', 
                 host='172.16.10.27', 
                 user='wn')
res <-dbSendQuery(con, "select time, location, freq from mainsfrequency where valid=1 and time >= '2021-08-02T00:00:00.0Z' and time < '2021-08-03T00:00:00.0Z'")
frequencies <- dbFetch(res)
dbClearResult(res)
dbDisconnect(con)

freq_wide <- frequencies %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = location, 
              values_from = freq, 
              values_fn = mean)
```

The result tipple looks like this:
[image]

Occasionally there are measurement error in the data, like this one

[image]

These errors can be recognize by the gradient to the previous and the next value. I want to remove these errors before calculating sd or mad on the rows of the tipple.

However, the only way I want looks more like C than like R: two nested loops:

```
THRESHOLD <- 0.5

for (colIdx in 2:length(freq_wide)) {
  last <- freq_wide[[1, colIdx]]
  for (rowIdx in 1:length(freq_wide[[colIdx]])) {
    current <- freq_wide[[rowIdx, colIdx]]
    if (!is.na(current) && !is.na(last) && (abs(current - last) > THRESHOLD)) {
      freq_wide[[rowIdx, colIdx]] = NA
    }
    last <- current
  }
}
```

**Is there any more R-ish way to solve this problem, I mean, to remove the measurement errors?** It appears to me that I definitely need the previous value in the particular column. However, I found no way in the tidyr or dplyr functions I looked in to get access to this value.

The remaining script is

```
freq_wide <- freq_wide %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(sd = sd(c_across(names(freq_wide)[-1]), 
                 na.rm=TRUE))

print(summary(freq_wide))
print(sum(freq_wide$sd))
```

and the data I'm working on can be seens here https://grafana.mainscnt.eu

Thank you very much!
Wolfgang

Answer (score 1):

A more R-ish way or at least a `tidyverse` approach may look like so:

1. As far as I get it there is probably no reason to reshape your data to wide format. Instead you could go on with the data in long format and make use of `group_by` + `summarise` to compute the means by location and time
2. To compute your gradients or check whether the gradient is larger than your threshold you could `group_by` location and make use of `dplyr::lag`

BTW: It's called `tibble` not tipple. (;

```r
# Make some random example data
set.seed(42)

frequencies <- data.frame(
  time = seq(as.POSIXct("2021-08-02 23:59:00"), as.POSIXct("2021-08-02 23:59:30"), by = "1 sec"),
  location = rep(c("Luebeck_DE", "Dordrecht_NL"), each = 31),
  freq = rnorm(62, mean = 50, sd = .5)
)

THRESHOLD <- .5

library(dplyr)

frequencies %>% 
  group_by(location, time) %>% 
  summarise(freq = mean(freq, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  # Note: The additional group_by is not really necessary as the data 
  # is still grouped by 'location'. But I included it to avoid confusion.
  group_by(location) %>% 
  mutate(lag_freq = lag(freq, order_by = time),
         is_error = ifelse(!is.na(lag_freq), abs(freq - lag_freq) > THRESHOLD, FALSE),
         freq1 = ifelse(is_error, NA_real_, freq)) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'location'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 62 × 6
#>    location     time                 freq lag_freq is_error freq1
#>    <chr>        <dttm>              <dbl>    <dbl> <lgl>    <dbl>
#>  1 Dordrecht_NL 2021-08-02 23:59:00  50.4     NA   FALSE     50.4
#>  2 Dordrecht_NL 2021-08-02 23:59:01  50.5     50.4 FALSE     50.5
#>  3 Dordrecht_NL 2021-08-02 23:59:02  49.7     50.5 TRUE      NA  
#>  4 Dordrecht_NL 2021-08-02 23:59:03  50.3     49.7 TRUE      NA  
#>  5 Dordrecht_NL 2021-08-02 23:59:04  49.1     50.3 TRUE      NA  
#>  6 Dordrecht_NL 2021-08-02 23:59:05  49.6     49.1 FALSE     49.6
#>  7 Dordrecht_NL 2021-08-02 23:59:06  49.6     49.6 FALSE     49.6
#>  8 Dordrecht_NL 2021-08-02 23:59:07  48.8     49.6 TRUE      NA  
#>  9 Dordrecht_NL 2021-08-02 23:59:08  50.0     48.8 TRUE      NA  
#> 10 Dordrecht_NL 2021-08-02 23:59:09  50.1     50.0 FALSE     50.1
#> # … with 52 more rows
```